# how to trace emacs menu?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to see what `emacs` is doing when I choose an action from menu?
For example I'd like to see what lisp commands are executed when I click on

```
Tools --> Spell Checking --> Automatic spell checking
```

This could be useful for learning what to include to init file to enable automatic spell check by default. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menus are implemented as keymaps, and `describe-key` handles mouse events in general, so you can simply use:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> (select menu item)

In this instance we see:

```
<menu-bar> <tools> <spell> <flyspell-mode> runs the command
flyspell-mode, which is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
`flyspell.el'.

It is bound to <menu-bar> <tools> <spell> <flyspell-mode>.

(flyspell-mode &optional ARG)

Toggle on-the-fly spell checking (Flyspell mode).
[...]
```

Actually tracing lisp calls is really a different question (`trace-function`, the built-in `elp` profiling library, `debug-on-entry` and the two debuggers in general are all very useful tools), but in this case clicking a menu item simply calls its function interactively, so there's nothing much to trace :)